# why can't I create file in the folder with xpcom

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

I haved created the folder , code like that

```
 var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);



 var foStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
             .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
 filePath = path;
 file.initWithPath(filePath);
 if(file.exists() == false ) {
   file.create(0x01, 0644); 
 }
```

but when I create the file in the folder , there is a error show like that

Error: uncaught exception:

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsILocalFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)"
```

anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the directory permissions to 0755

Answer (score 1):

That error is usually due to file or directory permissions. You might want to take a look at the code examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O).

Comment: But I haved set the directory permissons is 0644 still don't work